# I need detailed instruction on how to recover a ZTE z828 lt from soft brick caused by Kingo root!

Tags: root-access

I need detailed instruction on how to recover a ZTE z828tl  from soft brick caused by Kingo root!

I bought this “simple mobile ZTE Midnight pro LTE” off eBay, and simple won't unlock it, so I can use it with anyone else, so I was playing with KingoRoot trying to root it, the computer version said root complete please donate, the phone rebooted into boot loop, I can access the stock recovery screen, but can't do a factory reset, and I can get to ftn!!!

Please help, I am a newbie to android, cell phones, but have messed with tablets for years, and usually can get a factory ROM restore for flashing, but this time I've searched all over without any luck..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing as you and ended up in a boot loop but then I wiped the cache when I entered recovery And then restarted phone, let it boot up for a while then it restarted on its own.  I immediately did the button combo for recovery again and then did a factory reset.  I downloaded SuperSU and was still rooted. Hope this works for you.  Please let us know.

Comment: so basically MTND G you did a factory reset installed SU right after and you was good?

Comment: To be more precise.  No. I wiped the cache.  Then let phone bootloop a few times and THEN did a factory reset.  Phone booted normally then I downloaded and installed SU and all was good.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing ADB and then going to FASTBOOT MODE inside of your phone or tablet.
Please download the the .img file for your version of android and device specific.

------Commands------
fastboot oem unlock
fastboot flash (.img file location)
fastboot reboot

that should fix it just setup your phone again!